# Paste table from Email body to an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want the sender and the body of my mail pasted in my Excel file.

I have reached as far as pasting the sender but when the body, which is a table is pasted, it destroys the format since it pastes in one cell.

How to paste the table inside my email next to the sender?

I think the code for pasting a table should start at the comment: 'Paste the table inside the email body here.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("ABV")

    i = 2

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
            If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= .Range("C1") Then
                With .Cells(i, 1)
                    .Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
                    .Columns.AutoFit
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                End With
                With .Cells(i, 2)
                    'Paste the table inside the email body here
                End With
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next OutlookMail
    End With

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

All the emails in this folder will contain a table, so I would like to loop as every sender and its table gets pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can address and copy the table within the email's body by this:

```
OutlookMail.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.Tables(1).Range.Copy
```

and then you paste it e. g. as values into your `Excel.Range`:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

If you want to paste in a different clipboard-supported format, try to get the ideal format with Excel's macro recorder. It results in something like this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1").Select
    .PasteSpecial Format:="Text"   ' or "HTML" or ...
```